# Cannot create file with Node.js fs.appendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have been trying to create a program which saves logs from a Slack team. I have most things working, but have so far been unable to use `fs.appendFile()` successfully, as the documentation claims it will create the file if it doesn't exist (and not to use `fs.exists()` or `fs.access()` beforehand to check), but I'm getting an ENOENT error.

This is my function:

```
var storeLog = function (username, type, channelName, message) {
    var pathArr = [loggingDir, type, channelName];
    var path = pathArr.join("/") + ".log";
    var fullMessage = username + ": " + message;
    fs.appendFile(path, fullMessage + "\r\n", function (err) {
        if (err && globalSettings.debugMode) {
            console.error("Error saving log:\n", err);
        }
        else if (globalSettings.debugMode) {
            console.info("Appended to " + path);
            console.info(fullMessage);
        }
    });

};
```

*(`globalSettings.debugMode` is true)*

The `err` variable has this result:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\path\in\settings\Direct Message\username.log'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\path\\in\\settings\\Direct Message\\username.log' }
```

Comment: You need to create target directory first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fs.appendFile()` requires you to create the directory in which it will create the file if it doesn't exist. It wont create the directory for you.

It is also the case for `fs.createWriteStream()` that you could also use with the `a` flag.

Comment: I've now added a few fs.mkdir() functions to run on startup if the directory doesn't exist. However, the directories aren't getting created, despite err in the callback not being truthy EDIT: WORKING NOW